# C#, decrease database access time

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework for retrieving a complex object which consists of properties and collections (and these collections could also consist of collections). The data itself is pretty small but the structure is quite complex. A simple example (in reality there are more properties and collections):

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Measurement1> MeasurementOnes {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Measurement2> MeasurementTwos {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
    public string PropertyOne {get; set;}
    public string PropertyTwo {get; set;}...etc
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildrenId {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Measurement3> MeasurementThrees {get; set;}
    public string PropertyThree {get; set;}
}
```

The above example is very simplified but gives an overview of the structure. All measurements are updated every minute (by an external API) and the properties could also be changed.

I need to load this structure from the database (we are using SQL Server) and pass it to an optimization algorithm. This must be done for all Parents every half hour. It takes about one second to load the structure from the database, which means that I can only optimize around 1800 Parents in the given time interval.

Of course I can try to optimize the queries, put on some indexes etc in the database and lower the retrieval time from the database from 1 second to say 0.7 seconds. Then I can at most optimize around 2500 Parents, but the requirement is 10000 (db access time must be less than 0.18 seconds). I don't know how much the performance would increase if I instead of using Entity framework wrote Stored procedures, however for me it seems that the object structure is the real issue because in order to retrieve all data multiple roundtrips to the database is required.

Since the data of a Parent is changed quite a lot between each interval I don't know if caching is the way to go.

Does anyone have any experience from a similar issue or any suggestions on how I should do in order to decrease the database access time by a factor 10?

Comment: proper indexes and data warehousing

Comment: Does everything change during that half hour or only some of the data?

Comment: I am a bit perplexed by the choice to use EF with this tight performance requirements.

Comment: Have you run a trace to determine whether the 1 second delay is in the database query, or used a `Stopwatch` to measure EF (Entity Framework) in your code?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen All collections will change during that half hour. New measurements are added.

Comment: I would start by creating a small test project that didn't use EF, and simply executed two SQL's, one for parents and one for children, using a data reader, reading everything into memory, and timing that. I find it really hard to believe that reading 10.000 parents + children should take 30 minutes in total (unless you have billions of children). Is memory an issue? *Can* you load all the data into memory at the same time?

Comment: @Steve The system is part of a bigger system that uses Entity framework. We do not have these scaling issues right now so in order to save development time, and to focus on the optimization we have chosen to use the provided db access mechanism.

Comment: first, i think this is not possible with SQL Server alone. consider using Redis to cache your data

Comment: @BernhardHofmann Yes and the db lookup time is around 1 second. I think it is due to the many table lookups. It is because of this I have considered changing the db schema.

Answer (score 3):

two things I would try:

- write a stored proc that returns multiple resultsets for the parents, childs, etc. write code to read the results and instantiate your objects
- have the stored proc use 'for xml' to create this structure on the db side in xml use xml deserializer to instantiate your objects

Answer (score 3):

Create indexes.

Your assumption that 1 second can be reduces to 0.7 is very naive. Indexes can reduce query time from minutes/seconds to milliseconds. Reading what amounts to a few rows of data should take milliseconds. Index all the primary keys, foreign keys and any other column this particular process uses to search for data - as this process is running all the time it make sense to optimise each query EF generates and executes. SQL Profiler can really help here, you can capture each query being sent by EF and check the query plan with SSMS.

[Here's a link for SQL Profiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2010/02/02/ado-net-entity-framework-and-net-4-sql-profiler-lazy-loading-of-entities.aspx) to get you started

(There other profiling tools available but you should already have SQL Profiler)

Comment: Upvoted because the performance improvement of adding the right indexes can indeed be monumental.